# Listview css not applied in Jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I try to make an mobile application in PhoneGap but the css not applied for `listview` .This is my html structure

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

The listview wil have a default css style,am I right ?Or I have to style in my css stylesheet?

P.S. I have included in head the jquery mobile scripts and the jquery mobile css.

Comment: yes it will have a default css style but it is to basic to add more style you have to css in it.

Answer (score 0):

try applying css using Id or Class

```
.myclass{
    //mention your style
}

#mydiv{
    //mention your style
}


<li div="mydiv"></li>
<li class="myclass"></li>
```